# Probability distribution leads to the 'Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)'

Tags: python, statistics, cpu, probability, montecarlo

I am trying to create some kind of a simplified Oracle Crystal Ball application for my geological studies that will use P90 (90% confidence) and P10 (10% confidence) values as inputs and return distribution of different probabilistic scenarios. Sounds like a Monte-Carlo distribution. I am new to Python, just started recently, btw :)

This topic will be separated into four key parts:

1. General description of the scope of the works.
2. Pseudocoding (never tried before, though).
3. Actual Python code.
4. The reason I am here or issues with logic/code.

**PART 1. General description of the scope of the works.**

1. For the simplicity, assume we have only three categories, each with P90 and P10 parameters without any steps between them:

   - cat_1: [1, 2]
   - cat_2: [2, 4]
   - cat_3: [3, 6]
2. Utilizing a Cartesian product, we get the following 8 lists with possible scenarios:

   - [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 6], [1, 4, 3], [1, 4, 6], [2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 6], [2, 4, 3], [2, 4, 6]
3. Multiplying parameters in every list leads to the following products:

   - [6, 12, 12, 24, 12, 24, 24, 48]
4. Measuring a frequency of every product leads to:

   - {6: 1, 12: 3, 24: 3, 48: 1}, or considering percentages to:
   - {6: 12.5%, 12: 37.5%, 24: 37.5%, 48: 12:5%,} which means that the probability of occuring 12 or 24 is higher than 6 or 48.
5. That's the result I would like to get: knowing the probability of the products to be able to get mean, median and mode values.
6. The difficult part for my hardware is a huge quantity of possible scenarios in real case. There are total six categories with small steps between P90 and P10 values. Considering metric system, range of the P90 and P10 values may be as following:

   - square area: 0.01 - 100.00 km2, step 0.01;
   - layer thickness: 0.10 - 100.00 m, step 0.1;
   - porosity: 0.01 - 1.00 p.u., step 0.01;
   - saturation: 0.01 - 1.00 p.u., step 0.01;
   - pressure: 1 - 2000 atm, step 1 atm;
   - surface: 0.01 - 1.00 p.u., step 0.01.
7. Usually, actual case studies will use much narrower ranges, say 0.1 - 2.0 km2 for squrea area, 1 - 10 m for thickness, 8 - 15 for porosity etc. Nontheless, even in this case it sounds like a 'google' amount of possible scenarios, considering the mentioned steps. As a result, I get the following notification, which is the key issue:

> Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL).

This occurs when the total amount of calculations exceeds ~10MM and ~1 minute (experimentally checked, hence the numbers are rough).

**PART 2. Pseudocoding.**

Good practice says one should not be to abstract while pseudocoding, however I have zero experience in this domain, hence will try my best.

```
User inputs minimum possible values (P90) for total 6 categories
User inputs maximum possible values (P10) for total 6 categories

Total 6 list are created (square area, layer thickness, porosity etc.), 1 per each category that contain a range of possible values and indicated step (P90_category1, P10_category1, step1)

Use a Cartesian product to create a list_of_tuples with possible scenarios

Convert list_of_tuples to the list_of_lists

Create empty_list
for each element in the list_of_lists:
    calculate its product
    append to the empty_list

Round values in the empty_list

Create a dictionary that counts similar values in the empty_list

Calculate a probability of each value according to its repetition frequency in the dictionary
```

That's it. Some basic statistics and plotting is also applied, however that is not a key moment here.

**PART 3. Actual Python code.**

At first P90 values (90% confidence):

```
P90_area = float(input('P90 area: '))
P90_thickness = float(input('P90 thickness: '))
P90_porosity = float(input('P90 porosity: '))
P90_saturation = float(input('P90 saturation: '))
P90_pressure = float(input('P90 pressure: '))
P90_surface = float(input('P90 surface: '))
```

Then P10 values (10% confidence):

```
P10_area = float(input('P10 area: '))
P10_thickness = float(input('P10 thickness: '))
P10_porosity = float(input('P10 porosity: '))
P10_saturation = float(input('P10 saturation: '))
P10_pressure = float(input('P10 pressure: '))
P10_surface = float(input('P10 surface: '))
```

Create a range of values from P90 to P10 with a particular step

```
area_values = np.arange(P90_area, P10_area + 0.01, 0.01)
thickness_values = np.arange(P90_thickness, P10_thickness + 0.1, 0.1)
porosity_values = np.arange(P90_porosity, P10_porosity + 0.01, 0.01)
saturation_range = np.arange(P90_saturation, P10_saturation + 0.01, 0.01)
pressure_range = np.arange(P90_pressure, P10_pressure + 1, 1)
surface_range = np.arange(P90_surface, P10_surface + 0.01, 0.01)
```

Combine all the lists into Cartesian product (i.e. [(area1, thickness1, porosity1), (area1, thickness1, porosity2) etc.]):

```
list_of_tuples = list(itertools.product(area_values, thickness_values, porosity_values, saturation_range, pressure_range, surface_range)
```

Convert list of tuples into list of lists:

```
list_of_lists = [list(elem) for elem in list_of_tuples]
```

Create a list with multiplied values and sort these ('np.prod' returns a product for each list):

```
multiplied_values = []
for i in list_of_lists:
    i = np.prod(np.array(i))
    multiplied_values.append(i)
multiplied_values = sorted(multiplied_values)
```

Round values:

```
rounded_values = [float(Decimal('%.2f' % elem)) for elem in multiplied_values]
```

Create a dictionary that counts all the similar/unique objects:

```
counts = Counter(rounded_values)
```

Calculate a probability by dividing value by the total number of elements in the list:

```
probability_mass = {k: v/total for k, v in counts.items()}
```

It works, here goes simple statistics and a diagram for a specific case:

- Total calculations: 4899510
- P90 is: 5.60
- P10 is: 43.41
- P50 (value with maximum probability) is: 15.24
- Mean value is: 23.80

[Figure. Probability distribution diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOT2k.png)

First question is crucial, because it blocks the calculation of the large stack of data:

**PART 4. Key issues.**

**Q1. Key problem:**

As a result, I get the following notification, which is the key issue:

> Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL).

According to the similar topics, most likely, my script was killed by the OS due to the excessive CPU usage. I checked the CPU load with *'top'* command while running code and CPU was loaded up to 100% when it could process the input parameters and in some moments up to 110% when being interrupted.

Specs: laptop Asus G531GU | i7-9750H CPU 2.60GHz | GeForce GTX 1660 TI, 6Gb | 16Gb DDR4 | Ubuntu 18 | PyCharm Community IDE.

**Question: *By any chance, how can I get rid of this interruption and let the script run as long as necessary? I am good with waiting as long as needed to get the right distribution for the large data stack. Increasing a step for each parameter is a hardcore option, I would not rather do this.***

**Q2**. Probability distribution diagram doesn't look like a classic Normal Distribution, while the difference between max probable and mean values is significant. What do you think, might there be any issues with the logic of the code?

P.S. I understand this script looks quite bumpy, hope your eyes will not bleed)

Comment: It sounds like you are implementing an approach which requires calculating every possibility. That's OK, that's a good way to get started. My advice at this point is first to reduce the number of values that need to be calculated by increasing the size of the steps in each variable. The step appears to be 0.01 at present, maybe try 0.1 instead. The idea is to get it working with a much smaller number of values and then try decreasing the step size (increasing the number of steps). Also, once you have a feel for the problem, look for a more analytic or symbolic approach. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: @RobertDodier thank you, Robert) Correct, the key idea is to calculate every possible scenario. This is smth that is widely used in geology when we do have a range of possible values for geological conditions (mentioned area, thickness etc.), however do not know the precise value, because direct measurements are absent at the moment. So I did what you wrote, started with small and was constantly increasing parameters and decreasing steps. That's smth that I will face in real case, that's why that interruption by OS is quite frustrating, since script works, but with relatively small ranges)

Comment: I would look at how the time to complete the calculation scales with the number of steps, and try to estimate how long it's going to take to do it with as many steps as I originally wanted. If that turns out to be too many, there are strategies to try to stay within the constraints of time and space. E.g. do a search with large steps to get in the neighborhood, and then small steps to refine. Or apply a heuristic search method such as simulated annealing, or a gradient-free search such as the polytope (amoeba) algorithm, or method which uses gradients (LBFGS, etc) if a gradient exists.

Comment: @RobertDodier so many terms I'm not familiar with, but that looks like a great chance to go further with it) Thank you for those tips and directions! I will comment here, should I have any new positive or negative results.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to calculate every possible scenario, the computation required here goes up exponentially with the number of elements in each of your ranges.
I would love to try and debug a complete code for you but I need the inputs, so can you post the full code with the inputs already specified so we know what are reasonable values to use.

On a slightly different note, rather than trying to fix your code, can we start by trying to solve your original problem? When you said "simplified Probability Distribution Calculator" what do you mean? Can you write the steps in psuedo-code for us to understand the process before we try to see how to implement that process in Python.

Depending on your answer to the above, I might suggest you do a sampling approach rather than evaluating every single possibility. Lookup Monte-Carlo simulation. If you have a prior distribution that you are updating with new data and you want to know the posterior (final) distribution then consider using Bayesian methods, specifically Winbugs (standalone program that is not Python but is ideal for Bayesian stuff).

PS. I know my answer is probably more appropriate to write as a comment but apparently you need +50 reputation for that and I'm not there yet :(

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer, Matthew! I will edit my post with suggested specifications and will comment here, so you could get the notification. Will do this these days, most likely on the weekend, though.

Comment: Matthew, just edited the initial post and added pseudocoding. Actually, I do want to do some kind of the Monte-Carlo simulation, you are right.

Comment: I have a few follow on questions based on your pseudocoding:
1) Since you give p10 and p90, you are implying that your parameters are following a probability distribution. I need to know which one. If you say they are Normally distributed then we run into issues with negative (impossible) values since the p10 is so close to zero that the lower tails of the distribution include a significant amount of negative numbers. More likely they will follow a Weibull or Lognormal distribution, or a truncated Normal distribution. Or if we draw a negative number then we could resample. Which do you want?

Comment: 2) I'm still not sure what you want to achieve as a find output. Can you word it like an exam question. eg. "Given X and Y, what is Z"

Comment: I had to indicate this in the message, but only positive parameters should be used. I didn't code any rules yet just to make it easier at this point.

Comment: Unfortunately less rules makes it harder. If you are trying to find the joint probability of a combination of properties (area, porosity, etc.), then you are effectively multiplying probability distributions together. You can't do that unless you know the type of distributions you are multiplying. This is a fairly simple problem to solve using a Monte Carlo simulation but I can't draw random samples from a distribution unless I know the distribution. If it is a uniform distribution we are sampling from then the answer will also be a uniform distribution so not very useful for you.

Comment: We have six categories, each has max confident (P90) and less confident (P10) inputs, denoted by user. Also we have a step between P90 and P10 for each category. Say, P90 is 1, P10 is 10, step is 1, hence we get 1, 2 , 3 ... 8, 9, 10. After that we calculate each possible scenario by having a Cartesian product for these data. As a result, P50 should be chosen among all the scenarios, as smth in the middle. Actually, this code works well, but with smaller ranges) It throws an error, mentioned in the topic, when I try to use much larger ranges between P90 and P10.

Comment: Currently you are creating your range of values using numpy.arange, then pairing them using your Cartesian product. It is my understanding that you want to find which combination occurs most frequently? If you do it this way then they all have the same frequency (of 1) as they are all unique combinations/tuples. Just choosing the middle of the joint distribution is equivalent to picking the middle of the inputs and combining those. See this diagram: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#/media/File:Cartesian_Product_qtl1.svg
You need an input distribution for this to make sense.

Comment: What is Cartesian product? A list of smaller_lists_aka_elements, right? Length of each smaller_lisk_aka_element is 6, since we have 6 categories (area, thickness, porosity etc.). Let's assume each category is a range between 1 to 10 with a step 1. After that I calculate a product of each smaller_list_aka_element: first element is 1*1*1*1*1*1, second one will be 1*1*1*1*1*2, tenth will be 1*1*1*1*1*10, eleventh will be 1*1*1*1*2*1 and so on, untill we get a product for each smaller_list_aka_element in the list. Actually, that leads to a decent result, see attached figure, which is a real case.

Comment: Ok, let's take a step back. I'm not trying to fix your SIGKILL issue because that is clearly caused by your code asking your computer to do too many calculations. I propose a method using a Monte Carlo simulation, but without knowing what you are trying to achieve, I cannot help you.
Can you tell me, what question you want to answer based on the specified inputs of p10 and p90 for each parameter?

Comment: Would it be correct to say: "I would like to know the mean, median, and mode of the joint probability distribution of each of the 6 parameters, where the individual probability distributions of each parameter are given by a weibull distribution with confidence intervals specified by the p10 and p90 limits specified by the user"?

Comment: First of all, I'm sorry that takes so much time. Most likely, that's because I don't have math and stats backround to explain in terms properly :) At this point I cannot say your suggestion is right or not, since I didn,t manage to understand what weubull distribution is. However, what might be more valuable, I highly rectified description of my task (Part 1), since I found there a mistake. I believe, now that makes sense and might be much more helpful than before. I would appreciate, should you be able to go through the 'Part 1' once more.

Comment: Hi Alex, Your revision is certainly possible as a Monte Carlo simulation and I can write this for you if you are sure that's what you want. Before I do, I need you to consider whether your method achieves anything meaningful. If you just multiply all your parameters together you'll have units of km^2.m.pu^3.atm. Seems like a weird thing to do to just multiply them together.
When we say "cartesian product" I need you to understand that the multiplication literally means "AND". You normally multiply probabilities rather than the actual units themselves. Have a think about it and let me know.

Comment: Hi Matthew, current approach works well. I checked outputs for the relatively small ranges in existing software and it produces the same, hence the key issue is an interruption. I do understand cartesian product means 'and', however the next step, as you could see, is multiplying these 'ands'. The reason for that is pretty simple: by multiplying all the mentioned parameters (area, thickness, porosity etc.) in geology we get a volume that stands for the reserves of oil/gas that might fit subsurfaces :) I would highly appreciate, should you be able to write this the way w/o interruptions! :)

Answer (score 0):

So I have done what you needed regarding the uniform distribution of input parameters, random sampling, and cartesian products. The result kind of looks like an exponential distribution. It is better modelled by a weibull distribution.

I did some further analysis as the results of any simulation should always be investigated further to check whether the simulation is sufficient. To do this, I have done a monte carlo sample of 10,100,1000,10000,100000,10000000 samples to produce the histogram. We see from the convergence in alpha and beta from the fitted weibull that 1 million samples is sufficient.

I'm sure you'll have questions about this so please ask them below. Note that the histogram plots are on log-log scale so you will need to keep that in mind when visualizing the distribution (or comment out the xscale and yscale lines).

Here are the results:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/viQ9i.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kc4n.png

And here is the code with the output generated:

```
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as ss

#these should be user inputs
area_min = 0.01
area_max = 100
thickness_min = 0.1
thickness_max = 100
porosity_min = 0.01
porosity_max = 1
saturation_min = 0.01
saturation_max = 1
pressure_min = 1
pressure_max = 2000
surface_min = 0.01
surface_max = 1

grid_resolution = 1000 #how finely we will slice each property. I have kept this consistent as it makes more sense to do so when sampling
#With a grid_resolution of 1000, the number of possible combinations here is 1000^6 ==> 10^18 so we will randomly sample the array
#I assume you want to get a probability distribution of these combinations.
area_array = np.linspace(area_min,area_max,grid_resolution)
thickness_array = np.linspace(thickness_min,thickness_max,grid_resolution)
porosity_array = np.linspace(porosity_min,porosity_max,grid_resolution)
saturation_array = np.linspace(saturation_min,saturation_max,grid_resolution)
pressure_array = np.linspace(pressure_min,pressure_max,grid_resolution)
surface_array = np.linspace(surface_min,surface_max,grid_resolution)

#it is important to try different sample sizes to be sure your sample is large enough
samples_to_test = [1,2,3,4,5,6] #log10 scale

xmax = 10**8
alpha_array = []
beta_array = []
plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
for i,s in enumerate(samples_to_test):
    plt.subplot(231+i)
    samples = 10**s
    product_array = []
    for _ in tqdm(range(samples)):
        area = random.choice(area_array)
        thickness = random.choice(thickness_array)
        porosity = random.choice(porosity_array)
        saturation = random.choice(saturation_array)
        pressure = random.choice(pressure_array)
        surface = random.choice(surface_array)
        product_array.append(area*thickness*porosity*saturation*pressure*surface)

    xvals = np.logspace(1,np.log10(xmax),1000)
    [beta,_,alpha] = ss.weibull_min.fit(data=product_array,floc=0)
    alpha_array.append(alpha)
    beta_array.append(beta)
    weibull_yvals = ss.weibull_min.pdf(xvals,beta,scale=alpha)
    plt.plot(xvals,weibull_yvals)
    print('Weibull fit parameters:\nalpha =',alpha,'\nbeta =',beta)
    [mean,variance] = ss.weibull_min.stats(beta, loc=0, scale=alpha, moments='mv')
    median = ss.weibull_min.median(beta, loc=0, scale=alpha)
    print('Mean =',mean)
    print('Median =',median)
    print('Standard deviation =',variance**0.5)

    plt.hist(product_array,bins=1000,density=True)
    plt.yscale('log')
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.xlabel('Cartesian Product of parameters')
    plt.ylabel('Probability density ($log_{10}$ scale)')
    plt.title(str('Monte Carlo samples = '+str(samples)))
    plt.xlim(10,xmax)
    plt.ylim(10**-8,0.0001)

plt.suptitle('Probability of of a given cartesian product of the specified parameters\nmeasured using different numbers of Monte Carlo samples')
plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
plt.subplot(121)
plt.semilogx(10**np.array(samples_to_test),alpha_array,label='alpha')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(122)
plt.semilogx(10**np.array(samples_to_test),beta_array,label='beta')
plt.legend()
plt.suptitle('Test results for alpha and beta')
plt.show()

Output:
100%|██████████| 10/10 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Weibull fit parameters:
alpha = 86642.0194345818 
beta = 0.4938259951069627
Mean = 177350.7081149186
Median = 41247.66458603765
Standard deviation = 403557.41514732403
100%|██████████| 100/100 [00:00<00:00, 100246.27it/s]
Weibull fit parameters:
alpha = 177861.91287733015 
beta = 0.6310314479279571
Mean = 251385.7124440623
Median = 99503.40459313976
Standard deviation = 415414.97618995525
100%|██████████| 1000/1000 [00:00<00:00, 199131.37it/s]
Weibull fit parameters:
alpha = 171932.22877129668 
beta = 0.5452693527437176
Mean = 296661.14084923535
Median = 87788.61401806296
Standard deviation = 589615.4680695855
100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:00<00:00, 179051.70it/s]
Weibull fit parameters:
alpha = 166909.86147776648 
beta = 0.5172460791589029
Mean = 314175.4976503747
Median = 82176.44526800542
Standard deviation = 670314.3944630618
100%|██████████| 100000/100000 [00:00<00:00, 144477.93it/s]
Weibull fit parameters:
alpha = 167711.26073670806 
beta = 0.5194333533253157
Mean = 313393.61873437575
Median = 82817.74728224205
Standard deviation = 664803.5086740599
100%|██████████| 1000000/1000000 [00:07<00:00, 140706.15it/s]
Weibull fit parameters:
alpha = 168089.6178189406 
beta = 0.5186379527889259
Mean = 314930.2501968761
Median = 82914.8108556469
Standard deviation = 669461.6904337168
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I do appreciate that! First unobvious thing is '231 + 1' - what is that? Second difficult part starts with 'for _ in tqdm' and up to the end of tis for cycle. Have no idea what is that. And the third one is related to the alpha/beta/weibull and up to the matplotlib. I tried to understand weibull by reading papers, however nothing helped, still have no clue)) The biggest issue is I don't get the general logic behing these calculations.

Comment: 231+i is used for the subplotting. So in the loop of samples to test i will be 0,1,2,3,4,5 so the tubplot will start as 231, then 232, then 233. Go lookup subplot for more info.
tqdm is a progress indicator. Not required here but nice to have for knowing how long your for loops are taking.
The "for _ in" is used in place of "for x in" because I'm not using the variable x so I just use _ to tell python not to store the counter.
As for the weibull distribution, it is a probability distribution that can take on a variety of shapes. Read wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution

Comment: The steps I have followed are:
1) create a linearly space array of the input parameters
2) randomly choose a value from each parameter
3) multiply all these randomly chosen values together
4) make a histogram out of the results
5) fit a probability distribution to the histogram (in this case a Weibull distribution)
6) print the mean, median, standard deviation of the weibull distribution

I have also checked that 1 million samples is enough by seeing if the results for the weibull distribution are very different between 100K and 1 million, which they are not. So more are not needed.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I think multiplying the random samples together is nonsense as you have units of  km^2.m.pu^3.atm.
If I was you, I'd want the joint probability distribution obtained by multiplying the marginal probabilities of each parameter together, and not by multiplying the parameters themselves. To do this you'd be better off sampling from a probability distribution such as a normal distribution, and not a uniform distribution as we have done with the linearly spaced arrays.
I know this is a lot of python and statistics combined but your problem needs it. Any other questions?